# Filtering a dataframe that has lists as a row element

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Trying to filter a `dataframe` using `iloc` and `isin` while looking for a results similar to `any`.

Data:

| column | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | [A] |
| 2 | [] |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | [A,B] |
| 5 | C |
| 6 | [C] |
| 7 | B |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"tags": ["A",["A"],[],"",["A","B"],"C",["C"],"B"]})
filter = ["A","C"]
```

Filtering:

```
df.loc[df["tags"].isin(filter)]
```

Result:

| column | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 5 | C |

Desired Result:

| column | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | [A] |
| 4 | [A,B] |
| 5 | C |
| 6 | [C] |

- I don't want to flatten the dataframe because it'll be costly for large dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set.intersection` in list comprehension and `if-else` because mixed lists and scalars for test and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"tags": ["A",["A"],[],"",["A","B"],"C",["C"],"B"]})

f = ["A","C"]
s = set(f)

df = df[[bool(s.intersection(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])) for x in df["tags"]]]

print (df)
     tags
0       A
1     [A]
4  [A, B]
5       C
6     [C]
```